# Cannot convert type 'object[][]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, list, ienumerable

I'm trying to create and consume a web service... I'm using .NET Framework 4.0 (c#).
The service exposes a method like this:

```
  public List<object[]> GetData(string strRegion, List<string> lstBrand, List<string> lstColor)
```

Then on the client application, I declare a list of objects:

```
  List<object[]> lst = new List<object[]>();
```

... and attempt to fill it like so:

```
  MyService.MyClient os = new MyClient();
  lst = os.GetData(myRegionString, myBrandList, myColorList);
```

... but I get, "Cannot implicity convert type 'object[][]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'". What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the service method doesn't actually return `List<object[]>`, but `object[][]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the solution explorer, right click your service and do configuration. You may have set the data collection default type to array. You can set it to be a list type. Also, I would rethink sending an `object` over a web service. You typically want a well defined data type. I don't think you can even send type `object` over a web service.

Comment: What do you mean, "...You typically want a well defined data type..." ?

Comment: A web service will provide a consumer with a WSDL file that describes the data type of each object/parameter. The type `Object` can be anything  and as such, can't be well defined. You would want to go with `int`, `string`, `double`, etc. You could have your own data type and that contained these basic data types. Then the WSDL would describe to the consumer what your custom datatype contains.

Comment: What if you want to send a list in which each list item contain objects such as strings, numbers and dates?

Comment: How would you know on the receiving end what type to cast that as?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
MyService.MyClient os = new MyClient();
  lst = os.GetData(myRegionString, myBrandList, myColorList).ToList();
```

Lists will get serialized into arrays as they are passed from the web service to the client, so you'll need to convert it back to a list again.

Answer (score 0):

The MyClient.GetData() method is returning a jagged array. To convert this array into a list, you should be able to use the ToList() method from the System.Linq namespace:

```
lst = os.GetData(myRegionString, myBrandList, myColorList).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you return a jagged array, not a generic list of object[]. One solution is already suggested - just change the type of the return value. But what I think is better is to use interfaces everywhere - both the array and the generic list implement IList, so if you make your method to return a value of type IList, and your lst variable is IList as well, then you shouldn't have problems even if your method returns a jagged array.